# Customization of Login Page Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-interface, web, amazon-cognito

I know that there is possibility to customize some values on login page provided by cognito. But it isn't enough for me. Is it possible to customize it completely? I'm using only third pard federated identification there from web application. Is there possiblility to change grey background? Or put there completely different view?

Comment: AWS Forum link to this change request https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=261520

Answer (score 12):

Since the background grey color can't be modified anymore, we can use some CSS tricks to change the background-color.

Just use multi-layer box-shadow and let the outside shadow be big enough to overlay the background.

Login screen:

[image: Login screen]

Doing something like:

```
.background-customizable {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 20%), 0 0 0 10000px #eee;
}
```

Comment: This will work if you do not have both federated and Cognito (username & password) service providers enabled.  At the time of this writing, Cognito will put in an "or" span with the same class ".background-customizable" in the middle of the dialog.  The "or" span with outside shadow will cover the dialog's content.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

The only reliable solution is reimplementing from scratch the whole "create account / reset password / social login" interface using the npm package `amazon-cognito-identity-js`.

As a quick fix, amazon actually does not perform validation on the CSS values which are entered on the "UI Customization" form: you can actually inject any CSS you wish.

I would not rely on this for anything important, as it may not work for a long time, but it can be OK for a personal webpage / unpaid work / proof of concept that you need to show to investors for tomorrow.

Enter this:

[image: enter this]

Get this:

[image: customized login page]

Comment: This no longer works. The console gives an error saying `The CSS class body is not in the list of allowed classes.`

Comment: It worked just fine for me. I was using the Background > background-color property. One thing though is it seems to get stripped out by UI on page refresh

Comment: This worked for me too, and still works on page refresh.

Comment: From my attempts this only works when you provide a custom domain name under "Your own domain".  Then you can apply whatever CSS you like.

Comment: Is there a way to add Terms checkbox when signup ?

Comment: I've got this error: We were unable to update your pool's UI customization: The CSS class body is not in the list of allowed classes.

Comment: @ImanShafiei body is not allowed. You can only custom some class specify here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-ui-customization.html

Comment: Still works as of Dec 2022. I was able to set color for description and text.

Answer (score 1):

[Amazon Cognito UI Customization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-ui-customization.html)

Here you can see all the possible UI customization that are available by AWS Cognito. Apart from that, There is no option to modify the other things.

Apply your convinient CSS and you can see the changes on Sign Up / Sign IN Page.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I saw this. "Customization" in aws case is really poor unfortunately.

Comment: Yes i agree with you. But as we are using Amazon's cognito authentication they have kept little monopoly on their side :)
You must have to use this CSS only!

Comment: Is there a way to add Terms checkbox when signup ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `amazon-cognito-identity.js` and create your own authentication pages such as login page, logout page, session expire etc.

Because in order to meet all your requirements in the later stage as well you probably have to move to a custom UI, so better do it now in an early stage.

Here are the sources which have helped me a lot while building my own authentication pages. You can refer these videos episode by episode from start to end.

> source link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WZmIdXZe3Q&t=182s

Answer (score -1):

You can customize Cognito using any backend language on AWS LAMBDA and importing the Cognito package on AWS lambda and connecting it to AWS API GATEWAY from where you can create a post request to AWS LAMBDA and AWS LAMBDA will authenticate whether the user should be log in or not.

Comment: Could you please give specific details on this solution? Do you have any tutorials or helpful links?