# How to center the AWS Cognito Login Form?

Tags: css, amazon-cognito

I am trying to change the CSS of the AWS Cognito login form, it has a very restricted list of CSS classes that can be changed, here's the list of allowed CSS classes:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-ui-customization.html

By default, the form modal is stick at the top. And we cannot change the `modal-dialog` class to align it to the center

How to make it vertically center aligned ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First switch to the new console of AWS cognito service. There check under **App integration**
[image: AWS Cognito new console]

Under the Hosted UI section you can upload the new CSS file, it still doesn't allow the classes not listed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-ui-customization.html but we can use a work around.

[image: Hosted UI section]

Make use of the class `background-customizable` (this is in the allowed list) to change the vertical position by adding `margin-top: 20vh`, and then upload it. You can adjust the vertical position by modifying the `margin-top`. `20vh` works for my devices. You can add changes accordingly.

```
.background-customizable {
    margin-top: 20vh;
}
```

You can also change the background using `box-shadow` hack, increase the box shadow length and change it's color, something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72302510/9543932